# Flushing the bean cache

Tags: java, caching, weblogic-10.x, ejb-2.x

I am working with a system that uses EJB 2. The system consists of two separate applications, one is for user management and the other is the actual application containing business logic.

In the business logic application I have a bean managed entity bean that represents a User. 
The application reads information from the user management database, but cannot modify it.

Whenever a user is modified in the user management application, the business logic application is notified that the user has changed. This is implemented as a call to the business application to remove the bean, which causes Weblogic to remove it from the cache and to "delete" it (which does nothing - see code for ejbRemove below). The next time the business application needs the user it will re-load it from the database.

We use the following code to invalidate a single user:

```
    try
    {
        UserHome home = (UserAuthHome) getHome("User", UserHome.class);

        User ua = home.findByPrimaryKey(user);
        ua.remove();  // This will remove a single cached User bean in the business logic application
    }
    catch ...
```

This works fine, but sometimes (epsecially when doing development) **I need to invalidate all cached User beans** in the business application. I would like to do this programatically - starting the management console takes too long. There are too many users to do a call for every user.

Possible solutions could include:

--Accessing the bean cache and get a list of the cached User beans.

--Telling WLS to scrap all items in the current User bean cache and re-read them from the database.

Unfortunately I don't know how to do either of these. 
I tried to search for a solution, but my internet search karma didn't find anything useful.

*Additional information:*

**Persistance:**

```
  <persistence-type>Bean</persistence-type>
  <reentrant>false</reentrant>
```

**Caching:**

```
<entity-descriptor>
  <entity-cache>
    <max-beans-in-cache>500</max-beans-in-cache>
    <concurrency-strategy>Exclusive</concurrency-strategy>
    <cache-between-transactions>true</cache-between-transactions>
  </entity-cache>
  <persistence></persistence>
</entity-descriptor>
```

**Bean Code (in the business application):**

```
public void ejbLoad()
{
    thisLogger().entering(getUser(m_ctx), "ejbLoad()");

    // Here comes some code that connects to the user database and fetches the bean data.
    ...
}

public void ejbRemove()
{
    // This method does nothing
}

public void ejbStore()
{
    // This method does nothing
}

public void ejbPostCreate()
{
    // This method is empty
}

/**
 * Required by EJB spec.
 * <p>
 * This method always throws CreateException since this entity is read only.
 * The remote reference should be obtained by calling ejbFindByPrimaryKey().
 *
 * @return
 * @exception CreateException
 * Always thrown
 */
public String ejbCreate()
    throws CreateException
{
    throw new CreateException("This entity should be called via ejbFindByPrimaryKey()");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did som additional research and was able to find a solution to my problem.

I was able to use `weblogic.ejb.CachingHome.invalidateAll()`. However, to do so I had to change the concurrency strategy of my bean to `ReadOnly`. Apparantly, `Exclusive` concurrency won't make the home interface implement `weblogic.ejb.CachingHome`:

```
<entity-descriptor>
  <entity-cache>
    <max-beans-in-cache>500</max-beans-in-cache>
    <read-timeout-seconds>0</read-timeout-seconds>
    <concurrency-strategy>ReadOnly</concurrency-strategy>
    <cache-between-transactions>true</cache-between-transactions>
  </entity-cache>
  <persistence></persistence>
</entity-descriptor>
```

And finally, the code for my new function `invalidateAllUsers`:

```
public void invalidateAllUsers() {
    logger.entering(getUser(ctx), "invalidateAll()"); // getUser returns a string with the current user ( context.getCallerPrincipal().getName() ).

    try {
        UserHome home = (UserAuthHome) getHome("User", UserHome.class); // Looks up the home interface
        CachingHome cache = (CachingHome)home;  // Sweet weblogic magic!
        cache.invalidateAll();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        logger.severe(getUser(ctx), "invalidate(date)", "got RemoteException", e);
        throw new EJBException(e);
    }
}
```